Выполнить перенаправление на читаемый url, относительно правил
/?do=news
Правило
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)(?:/([a-z-]+))?$ index.php?do=$1&po=$2 [QSA]

Страница доступна по адресу: /news/323 или /news/
Когда открываю страницу /?do=news или /?do=news&po=323. Страница доступна, содержимое верно, новость или список новостей. Но url остается прежним, возможно поправить правило так, чтобы автоматом перенаправляло на читаемый url?
